# Pass string to Dialog in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, modal-dialog

I have a form and from this I call

```
dialogPrintDiet.ShowDialog()
```

which launchs my dialog. I need to pass a string value and need the easiest way to do this in VB.NET .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try properties, for example setting some text boxes in your dialog:

```
Property FirstName() As String
    Get
        Return txtFirstName.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        txtFirstName.Text = Value
    End Set
End Property
Property LastName() As String
    Get
        Return txtLastName.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        txtLastName.Text = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: how do i acess FirstName in the dialog. I am using myForm.Member and it show in intellesence but is alway assigned 'nothing' even tho I am setting it right before I call the dialog. Sorry for these stupid question but I am not used of VB :(

Answer (score 2):

You can either add a property to the form or you can add a parameter to your form's constructor.

An example of the first method would look like (where Message is the name of the property)

```
frm.Message = "Some text"
```

An example of the second method would look like

```
Dim frm As New SampleForm ( "Some text" )
```

Your form code would be something like

```
Public Class SampleForm

Private someMessage As String


Public Sub New(ByVal msg As String)
    InitializeComponent()

    If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(msg)) Then
        someMessage = msg
    End If
End Sub

Property Message() As String
    Get
        Return someMessage
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        someMessage = Value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```